# Convert the formula to CNF and DNF

Tags: logic

I want to convert this formula:

$\neg(\neg(p \implies \neg g) \land (r \iff \neg p))$

My proccess:

$\neg(\neg(\neg p \lor \neg g)  \land ((r \implies \neg p) \lor (\neg p \implies r)))$

(De morgan)

$\neg ((p \land g) \land ((\neg r \lor \neg p) \lor (p \lor r)))$

Now I lost. Can anybody help mi pleas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible way to transform the formula.

1. $\neg(\neg(p \Rightarrow\neg g) \land (r \Rightarrow\neg p) \land
       (\neg p \Rightarrow r))\quad$ (equivalence)
2. $\neg(\neg(\neg p \vee \neg g) \land (\neg r \vee \neg p) \land
       (\neg\neg p \vee r))\quad$ (implication)
3. $\neg(\neg(\neg p \vee \neg g) \land (\neg r \vee \neg p) \land (
       p \vee r))\quad$ (double negation)
4. $\neg(( p \land  g) \land (\neg r \vee \neg p) \land (
       p \vee r))\quad$ (De Morgan)
5. $(\neg( p \land  g) \vee \neg(\neg r \vee \neg p) \vee \neg(
       p \vee r))\quad$ (De Morgan)
6. $(\neg p \vee  \neg g \vee (r \land p) \vee (\neg p \land \neg r))\quad$ (De Morgan, double negation)
7. $(\neg g \vee ((\neg p  \vee r) \land (\neg p \vee  p)) \vee (\neg p \land \neg r))\quad$ (distributive laws)
8. $(\neg g \vee \neg p  \vee r \vee (\neg p \land \neg r))\quad$ (remove tautology)
9. $(\neg g \vee \neg p  \vee (r \vee  \neg p) \land (r \vee \neg r))\quad$ (distributive laws)
10. $(\neg g \vee \neg p  \vee r \vee  \neg p)\quad$ (remove tautology)
11. $(\neg g \vee \neg p  \vee r)\quad$ (remove one of the two $\neg p$)

Formula 11. is *both* the disjunctive normal form (**DNF**) *and* the conjunctive normal form (**CNF**) of the original formula.